# How to store value in hyperlink link selected row in gridview asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I have a gridview.I have a hyperlink field and I want that when I click on hyperlink field, then row value is store in session and page redirect to other page. How can I do this?

Here is my aspx markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Height="36px" 
    style="margin-left: 270px; margin-top: 92px" Width="232px" CellPadding="3" 
    BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" 
    BorderWidth="1px" onrowcancelingedit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
    onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing" onrowupdated="GridView1_RowUpdated" 
    onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    onrowdeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting">
    <Columns>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Table Name">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTBL" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Table_Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Table_Name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>


        <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Operation" ShowEditButton="True" 
            ShowDeleteButton="True" />

        <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:HyperLink  Text="Select" ID="lnkSelect" runat="server" CommandName="Select" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
</asp:GridView>
```

And here is my code behind :

```
public partial class DisplayTable : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         if (!Page.IsPostBack)
         {
             // Retrieve database gridview
             gettable();
         }
    }

    public void gettable()
    {
        // here is code 
    } 

    //here all code included regarding to edit,delete etc
    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = ((HyperLink)GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text;
        Session["destype"] = s;
        Page.Response.Redirect("home.aspx");
    }

    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        // base.VerifyRenderingInServerForm(control);
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please include relevant code only?

Comment: @un-lucky Ok let me correct

Comment: @un-lucky Now check please.My aspx code include all code because i want to reterive 'Table'Name' row value when i select hyperlink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope following will work for you, Not sure as not tested by me.

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow gr = ((sender as HyperLink).NamingContainer as GridViewRow);
    Session["destype"] = gr.Cells[0].Text.Trim(); /*For first cell value of Row */
    //Session["abc"] = gr.Cells[2].Text.Trim(); /*Repeat for other cell values of Row by increasing cell index */
    Response.Redirect("~/home.aspx");        
}
```

Also have look on [Send (Pass) GridView Row Values to next page using Session variable in ASP.Net](http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/133899/Send-Pass-GridView-Row-Values-to-next-page-using-Session-variable-in-ASPNet/)

Comment: I try but this is not working @Rahul. Hyperlink not working.When move cursor on hyperlink then nothing works.

Comment: why you don't use LinkButton instead of Hyperlink?

Comment: Ok can u do this?How can i add link button?

Comment: `<asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:LinkButton Text="Select" ID="lnkSelect" runat="server" CommandName="Select" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>` is this ok?

Answer (score 0):

I've never been a fan of accessing information by cell reference when it comes from a backing store like a database.

There are a number of ways to accomplish this.  I prefer making the information available to the link button.

In your markup you can do this:

```
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton Text="Select" ID="lnkSelect" runat="server"
                       data-tablename='<%# Eval("Table_Name") %>' 
                       CommandName="Select" 

                       // And consider doing this as often as needed
                       // It should be self evident :)
                       CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"
        />
    </ItemTemplate>
```

or equivalently, in the RowDatabound Event:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound( object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e ) {
        if ( e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow ) {
            DataRowView drv = (DataRowView) e.Row.DataItem ;
            LinkButton lnkSelect = (LinkButton) e.Row.FindControl("lnkSelect");

            lnkSelect.Attributes["data-tablename"] = drv["Table_Name"];
        }
    }
```

then in `SelectedIndexChanged`

```
    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gv = (GridView) sender;
        LinkButton lnkSelect = ( LinkButton ) gv.Rows[ gv.SelectedIndex ].FindControl( "lnkSelect" );

        Session[ "destype" ] = lnkSelect.Attributes[ "data-tablename" ];
        Page.Response.Redirect("home.aspx");
    }
```

or in `RowCommand`

```
    protected void GridView1_RowCommand( object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e ) {
        if ( e.CommandName == "Select" ) {
            LinkButton lnkSelect = ( LinkButton ) e.CommandSource;
            Session[ "destype" ] = lnkSelect.Attributes[ "data-tablename" ];
            Page.Response.Redirect("home.aspx");
        }
    }
```

---

**Addendum**

NOTE: Hyperlinks are not reliable if you do not provide an `href`. Since you need to postback first before redirecting to home.aspx, change the `HyperLink` to a `LinkButton`. I've revised my entire answer accordingly.

In the aspx markup, modify the hyperlink with this:

```
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSelect" runat="server"
                        Text="Select" 
                        CommandName="Select" 
                        data-tablename='<%# Eval("Table_Name") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
```

And in `SelectedIndexChanged` do this

```
    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gv = (GridView) sender;
        LinkButton lnkSelect = ( LinkButton ) gv.Rows[ gv.SelectedIndex ].FindControl( "lnkSelect" );

        Session[ "destype" ] = (string) lnkSelect.Attributes[ "data-tablename" ];
        Page.Response.Redirect("home.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for response.This is complex code and confusing can u modify my code just little bit changing because if i write your according or do according to your logic then my whole project will be disturb :( :(

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by disturbed, but I'll simplify my answer.  I gave you two ways to do it. but I'll review you code and try to keep changes to a minimum.  I'm going on the assumption that all you need to do is save `Table_Name` to a session variable and redirect to `home.aspx`